# mysql - What should I use instead of IN statement?

Tags: mysql

In the following mysql query I'm trying to select all products that have ALL the features in the parenthesis. I'm using IN that apparently returns products that have feature 1 OR feature 2 etc... What should I use instead of IN?

```
SELECT *, f.name as feature, p.productcode as productcode, p.name as name 
from product p 
left join productfeatures pf on p.productcode = pf.productcode 
left join features f on pf.featureid = f.id
where f.id in (1, 2, 3) 
group by p.productcode
```

Comment: Does this SQL query run fine? I guess not.

Comment: Yes, apart from the fact that it return products that have ANY feature in the features array

Comment: But you don't want to return projects that have ANY feature, you wanted to return products that have ALL features, right?

Comment: Yes. I want products that have all three (1,2,3) features.

Answer (score 4):

add this to the end

```
having count(f.id) = 3
```

That will only result groups that have 3 `f.id`s and not just 1 or 2.

if you have more that 3 `f.id`s in your `in` clause, you need to extend that value. Example:

```
where f.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
group by p.productcode    
having count(f.id) = 5
```

Comment: What if an item has f.id = 1,2,4? it should not be shown, but it will get shown now.

Comment: that groups will already be filtered out due to the `f.id in (1, 2, 3)`